# Function return type based on state of data fetching inside function (loading, loaded, error)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, return-type, swr

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mclean-csm60i?file=/src/useFetch.ts

My types:

```js
type TUseFetchLoadingState = {
    loading: true;
    data: never;
    update: never;
    mutate: never;
    error: never;
};

type TUseFetchLoadedState<T> = {
    data: T;
    loading: never;
    update: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
    mutate: KeyedMutator<T>;
    error: never;
};

type TUseFetchErrorState = {
    error: AxiosError;
    loading: never;
    data: never;
    update: never;
    mutate: never;
};

type TUseFetchReturnType<T> = TUseFetchLoadingState | TUseFetchLoadedState<T> | TUseFetchErrorState;
```

Hook:

```js
const useFetch = <T>(url: string | null): TUseFetchReturnType<T> => {
    const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR<T, AxiosError>(url ? url : null);
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<T>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) setFetchedData(data);
    }, [data]);

    if (!fetchedData && !error) {
        return {
            loading: true,
        };
    }

    if (error) {
        return {
            error,
        };
    }

    return {
        data: fetchedData as T,
        update: setFetchedData as Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
        mutate,
    };
};
```

The idea of the hook is that when I retrieve data from server (server-side state) I store it in a local state so that I can change UI without waiting for server-side state to revalidate and update UI.

I want to type return type of the function properly so that when there's no data and no error, its return type would be `{ loading:true }` so later in a component I can typeguard.

```js
...
if (!loading) { ... } // means there's either data or error
...
if (!error) { ... } // means no error, data fetched successfully
```

When data is retrieved without any errors it should return data, data setter and mutator for immediate revalidation of server-side state.

When there's an error I want to only return `error` object.

How I want it to use in a component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, update, loading, error, mutate } = useFetch(ENDPOINTS.SOME_ENDPOINT);
  
  if (error) return <ErrorComponent error={error} />

  if (loading) return <LoadingComponent />
  
  // data is available, do something with it
  return (
    <Box>
      {/*do something with data*/}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I did something similar with props

```js
type RequiredTableToolbarProps = {
    title: string;
};

type SelectableTableToolbarProps = RequiredTableToolbarProps & {
    numSelected: number;
    onDeleteSelected: () => void | Promise<void>;
};

type NonSelectableTableToolbarProps = RequiredTableToolbarProps & {
    numSelected: never;
    onDeleteSelected: never;
};

export type TableToolbarProps = SelectableTableToolbarProps | NonSelectableTableToolbarProps;
```

And it worked like a charm: either component have both `numSelected` and `onDeleteSelected` or none.

How can I do the same thing with function return type?

Answer (score 0):

Make all types that has fields with `never` type optional.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mclean-csm60i?file=/src/useFetch.ts

Solution:

```js
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import useSWR, { KeyedMutator } from 'swr';

export { useFetch };

type TUseFetchLoading = {
    loading: true;
    data?: never;
    update?: never;
    mutate?: never;
    error?: never;
};

type TUseFetchLoaded<T> = {
    data: T;
    loading?: never;
    update: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
    mutate: KeyedMutator<T>;
    error?: never;
};

type TUseFetchError = {
    error: AxiosError;
    loading?: never;
    data?: never;
    update?: never;
    mutate?: never;
};

type TUseFetchReturnType<T> = TUseFetchLoading | TUseFetchLoaded<T> | TUseFetchError;

const useFetch = <T>(url: string | null): TUseFetchReturnType<T> => {
    const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR<T, AxiosError>(url ? url : null);
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<T>(undefined as unknown as T);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) setFetchedData(data);
    }, [data]);

    if (!fetchedData && !error) {
        return { loading: true };
    }

    if (error) {
        return {
            error,
        };
    }

    return {
        data: fetchedData,
        update: setFetchedData,
        mutate,
    };
};
```